# How to run Testcontainers on a different host

Tags: windows, macos, docker, testcontainers

My 16GB MBP is getting really slow when lots of Testcontainers are started. I'd like to run them on my beefy desktop, which is running Windows. Even better if this works from outside my local network.

Answer (score 9):

First, install a VPN (eg Tailscale) on both machines. You need to do that because Testcontainers is using random ports, so you can't just redirect the ports you use but need to be able to fully access all possible ports on an interface.

**Client**

Then on the client invoking the tests using Testcontainers, edit some files.

In ~/.docker-java.properties or C:/Users/myuser/.docker-java.properties:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://DOCKER_HOST_VPN_IP:2375
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0
```

In ~/.testcontainers.properties or C:/Users/myuser/.testcontainers.properties:

```
docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy
```

**Server**

On the machine running the Docker containers:

Enable "Expose daemon" in "Settings > General" in Docker Desktop.

**On Windows:**

Run in an elevated command prompt to forward packets from the Tailscale IP to local Docker:
`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2375 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=2375 listenaddress=<WINDOWS_VPN_IP> protocol=tcp`

Disable Firewall for private networks.

**On Linux:**

Use `IPTABLES` to route traffic incoming on port 2375 to 127.0.0.1:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2375 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2375
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE.
```

References

[2] https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md

[2] https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Michael's answer, I've created a [Helm chart](https://github.com/redsk/docker-tailscale) for installing a Docker server on Kubernetes that uses Tailscale as VPN.